# How to select child node with XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get values from a XML document using the iXF format, but I'm having some issues with the XPath syntax.

I have the following XML document

```
<SOAP_ENV:Envelope xmlns:NS2="http://www.ixfstd.org/std/ns/core/classBehaviors/links/1.0" xmlns:NS1="CATIA/V5/Electrical/1.0" xmlns:tns="IXF_Schema.xsd" xmlns:ixf="http://www.ixfstd.org/std/ns/core/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP_ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xsi:schemaLocation="IXF_Schema.xsd ElectricalSchema.xsd">
    <SOAP_ENV:Body>
        <ixf:object id="Electrical Physical System00000089.1" xsi:type="tns:Harness">
            <tns:Name>Electrical Physical System00000089.1</tns:Name>
        </ixf:object>
        <ixf:object id="X10(1)//X11(1)" xsi:type="tns:Wire">
            <tns:Name>X10(1)//X11(1)</tns:Name>
            <NS1:Wire>
                <NS1:Length>763,752mm</NS1:Length>
                <NS1:Color>RD</NS1:Color>
                <NS1:OuterDiameter>1,32mm</NS1:OuterDiameter>
            </NS1:Wire>
        </ixf:object>
    </SOAP_ENV:Body>
</SOAP_ENV:Envelope>
```

And i'm trying to find all the Wire objects and get the Name and Length values with the following code.

```
XmlDocument xlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xlDocument.Load(importFile);

XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xlDocument.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("tns", "IXF_Schema.xsd");
nsManager.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
nsManager.AddNamespace("ixf", "http://www.ixfstd.org/std/ns/core/1.0");
nsManager.AddNamespace("NS1", "CATIA/V6/Electrical/1.0");
nsManager.AddNamespace("NS2", "http://www.ixfstd.org/std/ns/core/classBehaviors/links/1.0");
             
//Get all wire objects
XmlNodeList wires = xlDocument.SelectNodes("descendant::ixf:object[@xsi:type = \"tns:Wire\"]", nsManager);

foreach (XmlNode wire in wires)
{
    string wireName;
    string wireLength;

    XmlNode node = wire.SelectSingleNode("./tns:Name", nsManager);
    wireName = node.InnerText;
    
    XmlNode node1 = wire.SelectSingleNode("./NS1:Wire/NS1:Length", nsManager);            
    wireLength = node1.InnerText;
}
```

I can get the wireName value without any problems but the Length element selection always returns 0 matches and I can not figure out why. I also tried to only select the Wire element using the same syntax as the Name element `./NS1:Wire` but that also returns 0 matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML declares

```
                    xmlns:NS1="CATIA/V5/Electrical/1.0"
                                     ^^
```

Your C# declares a different namespacem

```
nsManager.AddNamespace("NS1", "CATIA/V6/Electrical/1.0")
                                     ^^
```

Make sure both namespaces match exactly.

---

Regarding your comment asking about the use of version numbers in namespaces...

It is an unfortunately common but certainly not widely accepted practice to include a version number in an XML namespace.  Realize that by doing so, you're effectively saying that every namespaced XML component (element or attribute) should now be considered to differ from its counterpart in the old namespace.  This is rarely what you want.

### See also

- [Should I use a Namespace of an XML file to identify its version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3145566/290085)
- [What are the best practices for versioning XML schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2014237/290085)

Comment: This was the issue, though I'm a bit confused about the namespace declarations since this is a format for exchanging information between different applications. One of our applications outputs the V5 namespace and another uses the V6. I will have to look into that more.